# regex returning true even if comma is not enclosed in double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

**Below is my regular expression.**

```
/^\\"[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&\\'\*\+-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~;,:<>()@\[\]]*\\"$/
```

It is working correctly apart from the fact that it is returning true    even if comma is not included in double quotes. 
       Why is it showing odd behaviour for a comma.

Eg a:b without quotes returns false while a,b without quotes returns true.

Experts can you please help

Comment: What text are you executing that regex on? Can you provide a small example please so I can test it for you? What is the regex supposed to be doing?

Comment: What are you trying to match? Just throwing up a long regex like that without any reference to what you want it to match (or test against) will make it hard for people to help you.

Comment: Well I am checking if the text & characters are enclosed in double quotes(escaped).If the characters are not enclosed in quotes then it should return false.So taking an example firstname:lastname or <firstname> not enclosed in quotes return false which is the desired effect.However firstname,lastname returns true which is not desired. Ideally "firstname,lastname" should be true

Answer (score 3):

Because you are creating a character range here :

```
/^\\"[a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&\\'\*\+-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~;,:<>()@\[\]]*\\"$/
                          ^^^^^
```

This means all characters from `+` to `/`, this includes also the `,`.

INside a character class, you don't need to escape the normal regex special characters, but there is another one, that get a special meaning the `-`.

So the correct character class would be

```
/^\\"[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\\'*+\-\/=?^_`{\|}~;,:<>()@\[\]]*\\"$/
```

The alternative would be to put the `-` at the start or the end of the character class, in that cases it would not create a range and does not need escaping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Stema. However this new character class did not solve the issue

Comment: In javascript it depends on how you create the regex, maybe you need double escaping, means `\\-`

Comment: Hey Stema apologies for my earlier comment.The modified reg-ex provided by you did work.I had implemented it wrongly earlier..thanks a lot again :)